# How to run Python Unit tests with XML output

Tags: python, linux, debian, python-module, python-unittest

I try to run Python unit tests on our continues integration server (Bamboo, running on Debian Jessie) with XML output so we can either mark build as fail or success according to the test results. I am currently struggling with the fact that I just cannot install `xmlrunner` module. This is what I have done

```
sudo apt-get install python-xmlrunner
python3 
>>> import xmlrunner 
ImportError: No module named 'xmlrunner'
```

So I tried `pip` but it says package is already installed

```
sudo pip install unittest-xml-reporting
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): unittest-xml-reporting in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Btw I can import this module with Python 2.7 which probably means that this `python-xmlrunner` package is installed only for 2.7 version.

And I run my test class through `python3 -m unittest discover project_name` with main method likes this  `unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='test-reports'))`

Answer (score 3):

You should install the runner using `pip`, and I think the package is just called `xmlrunner` (but maybe that is python 2.7)

```
pip install xmlrunner
```

Even better would be to everything inside [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). Then you can pass a `requirements.txt` with all your dependencies, and you do not need to `sudo` install anything. Then you can choose any python version you like, isolated from your global installation.

If you wnat to check if it is installed, and which version, use `pip freeze`

**EDIT**
If `pip install xmlrunner` does not work, try `pip install unittest-xml-reporting`. Thanks, [@scrutari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547270/scrutari)

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem, I was able to fix it by putting the following line above the import statements:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually we run tests using `python -m unittest`
If you used similar approach, it will run your test cases, but it won't generate XML file. So run your code like `python test.py`.